# In WordPress 3.x, I can't access posts from all blogs in the network

Tags: customization, multisite

I use WordPress a ton, but I'm somewhat new to multisite. Now that 3.0 has brought multisite into the main core, shouldn't there be an easy loop function that allows you to display the most recent posts from across your network, in a loop, for me to output in PHP as I want?

Does anybody know if this exists and I'm just missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't ([and won't](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13752)) support this natively.

The alternative is to write your own template with a custom request. (You might even have to drop down into MySQL - I'm not sure the built in Wordpress query system will be capable of this.)

Check out this plugin though: [WordPress MU Sitewide Tags Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/other_notes/) It might give you an acceptable compromise, or it might give you a starting place when coding your own approach.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. It seems so strange to me that they wouldn't build this as core functionality. Of course multisite users would want to have a Loop object that's global.

Comment: What I'm wondering is if I drop into $wpdb for custom SQL queries, can I use the returned data to instantiate a WP_Query object so I can use standard Loop functions to output the posts, or will I be stuck using mysql_fetch_array and other raw PHP to get to the post data? 

Thanks again.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting question. (Probably a valid question in its own right.) Without opening it up and having a look, I'd guess that it would be possible, but this is pure speculation. If you did this however, you'd lose data about the source blog. Maybe extend WP_Query? Or just go straight from the MySQL to PHP?